# Saving Unity GUI fields

Tags: csv, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity's native GUI (used to use NGUI / iGUI) and was wondering whether you can have fields or input from the native UI save to a CSV file? If that is possible, can you have multiple iterations of a build open and have OnButtonDown, an entry saved per user to the same csv file?

Literally just wanting to know whether Unity UI has that capability.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

That wouldn't be a Unity feature or even a UI feature, but if you design your program correctly (single access to the file at one time, append instead of overwrite), then yes, you can get the functionality that you want.